# Cancelling an A/B test

Tags: civimail

How do I cancel a scheduled A/B test? I have one scheduled for tomorrow, but found a type post scheduling that our proofreader missed. I know I can no longer edit this, but I want to cancel it and resent it: how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I found this, it just took a while to show up! It is under the mailings section, I guess I just need to give the server some time to refresh.

Comment: could you accept your answer so this question is flagged as resolved?